# Is there a wall that can be regarded as an adiabatic wall?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, adiabatic

I want to do thermodynamic experiments and need a wall that is approximately adiabatic. Does such a wall exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an adiabatic wall is one which prohibits heat transfer.  A 1" thick wall of styrofoam is an adequate approximation for an elementary lab experiment.